# check gets checked by click on its class

Tags: javascript, jquery

My goal is the checkbox will get selected even clicked outside checkbox. I mean it will check that checkbox even user clicks on td class="checktd". I already tried prop('checked',true) but this not works. Any idea how to do this?

Jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(".checktd").on("click", function () {

        $('.checkItem').prop('checked', true);

    });

</script>
```

Html:

```
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: left;    
}
</style>


<table style="width:40%">
  <tr>
    <th>Check</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Telephone</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="checktd"><input type="checkbox" class="checkItem"></td>
    <td>Bill Gates</td>
    <td>55577854</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="checktd"><input type="checkbox" name="checkItem"></td>
    <td>Kevin Gates</td>
    <td>544444</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: ...say that 10 times faster... (re:title)

Comment: `$(this).find('.checkItem')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way you can "toggle", not only "check".

See that I included an IF inside, to check for currentTarget. That's because if you click on the checkbox itself it would "toggle" two times.

```js
$(function () {
   $(".checktd").on("click", function (e) {
      if (this != e.target) { return; }
      var check = $(this).find("input[type=checkbox]");
      check .prop('checked', !check[0].checked);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: left;    
}
</style>


<table style="width:40%">
  <tr>
    <th>Check</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Telephone</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="checktd"><input type="checkbox" class="checkItem"></td>
    <td>Bill Gates</td>
    <td>55577854</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="checktd"><input type="checkbox" name="checkItem"></td>
    <td>Kevin Gates</td>
    <td>544444</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rewrote my answer completely .

2 click handlers are used here. The second one finds the click on `.checkItem` and then stops the click event from propagating upward to its parent i.e. `.checktd`.  The first one finds the click on `.checktd`, then holds the checkbox with class `checkItem` in variable `$cb`.Then it checks whether the checkbox is checked. If checked , then it is unchecked. If not then reverse thing takes place. If the click event takes place exactly on the checkbox, then the event propagation is stopped so that the checkbox behaves as it is supposed to do without the  first click handler.

**N.B:** Your 2nd checkbox has `name="checkItem"`, I think you also want to use `class="checkItem"`, right ?

```
  $(".checktd").on("click", function (e) {

               var $cb=$(this).find('.checkItem');

               if($cb.prop('checked')){

                    $cb.prop('checked', false);
                }else{

                    $cb.prop('checked', true);
                }


            });
$(".checkItem").on("click", function (e) {

               e.stopPropagation();


            });
```

Comment: no this selects all of check boxes. i want to be selected only which td was clicked

Comment: answer re-written

Answer (score 0):

This should be what you tried to achieve (note that i made the `tr` clickable instead of the `td` and i made it also possible to uncheck it again ( -> `toggle`) because i think this is more useful):

```js
$(".checktr").on("click", function () {
    var toggle = $(this).find('input').prop('checked');
    toggle = !toggle
    $(this).find('input').prop('checked', toggle);
});
```

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: left;    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width:40%">
  <tr>
    <th>Check</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Telephone</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="checktr">
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkItem"></td>
    <td>Bill Gates</td>
    <td>55577854</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="checktr">
    <td class="checktd"><input type="checkbox" name="checkItem"></td>
    <td>Kevin Gates</td>
    <td>544444</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#content').on( "click", function() {
    $(this).prop('checked', 'checked');
});
```

This should be in document.ready of jquery. This answer is in addition @Istiaque's answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Use this:**

*Basically, get the children `.checkItem` from the clicked TD*

```
$(this).children('.checkItem').prop('checked', true);
```

```js
$(".checktd").on("click", function() {

  $(this).children('.checkItem').prop('checked', true);

});
```

```css
.checktd {
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
  table,
  th,
  td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
  }
  
  th,
  td {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: left;
  }
</style>


<table style="width:40%">
  <tr>
    <th>Check</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Telephone</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="checktd"><input type="checkbox" class="checkItem"></td>
    <td>Bill Gates</td>
    <td>55577854</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="checktd"><input type="checkbox" class="checkItem"></td>
    <td>Kevin Gates</td>
    <td>544444</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```